# how can I upgrade mongodb directly from 4.4 to 6.0?

Tags: linux, mongodb

After recent OS upgrade my mongodb is upgraded to 6.0. Then I have following error:

```
"msg":"Wrong mongod version","attr":{"error":"UPGRADE PROBLEM: Found an invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document (ERROR: Location4926900: Invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version: { _id: \"featureCompatibilityVersion\", version: \"4.4\" }
```

Since current distro does not provide 5.0 repo and We've already installed the mongo 6.0. It is difficult for me to install the mongodb 5.0 version. Is there a way to import 4.4 database in 6.0 server? Or is there a procedure to upgrade to 6.0 directly?

Comment: I assume you did not backup the database before you attempted to perform this upgrade? The documentation is clear with this regards, you must upgrade 4.4 to 5.0 in order to upgrade to 6.0. "To upgrade from a version earlier than the 5.0-series, you must successively upgrade major releases until you have upgraded to 5.0-series." I was able to find the mongodb 5.0.14 download without a issue on the mongodb website.

Comment: I end up install a mongodb-docker then use `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "5.0" } )`

Comment: This setFeatureCompatibilityVersion requirement is documented, but you typically don't know about it until AFTER you hit this issue AFTER you've upgraded unless you pored over their update docs.  IMHO it is SO PAINFUL, and imho lazy on the part of the mongodb devs to require this process flow, basically they just say to solve it, "revert your mongodb version and fix it".  So much harm and pain, I wish they would improve upon it for the sake of the end user of their software.  /rant